# How to compose an external data directory in PostgreSQL image within Docker?

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose

I'm trying to create a couple of containers with Docker. One is a `postgres:latest` image and the other is `ubuntu:latest` image with `postgresql-client` installed.

I have an existing database cluster in my localhost that I've used before install docker, of course. Now I want to use that cluster in my PostgreSQL container. The path in my computer is `/Users/Marco/Data`.

I've created a volume too, with the command `docker volume create --opt device=/Users/Marco/Data data_container` to store the cluster in it.

Then tried to make a `docker-compose.yml`file with the following content:

```
version: '2' 
services:
 db:
  image: postgres
  environment:
  - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/
  ports:
  - "5432:5432"
  volumes:
  - data_container:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata


 shell:
  image: ubuntu_pgsql
  command: /bin/bash
  tty: true
  stdin_open: true 
  links:
  - db

volumes:
 data_container:
  external: true
```

When I want to launch the containers with `docker-compose up -d` it shows me the following error:

```
ERROR: for db  Cannot start service db: error while mounting volume    '/var/lib/docker/volumes/data_container/_data': error while mounting volume  with options: type='' device='/Users/Marco/Data' o='': no such device
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

What could be failing? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If data container is a directory you should declare as:

```
volumes:
  - ./data_container:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
```

If you used a data_container without ./ before, docker compose understand that is a file, not a directory.

Comment: No, what I want to do exactly is: 1. Map my old cluster into a volume. 2. Use that volume with the PostgreSQL container.